# Microsoft Word - creating a double-sided letterhead template with only an image on the back

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, templates

I am attempting to create a Word template for letterhead that was designed in Illustrator. I am using headers and footers to recreate the look of the original letterhead. I'm running into a snag with the design of the back side of the letterhead. It has a company tagline printed on it, but is not meant to be typed on.

I am not sure how to automatically insert a page break or otherwise trick the program into skipping from the first page to the third page of the document without allowing any text on the "back" of the letterhead, yet allowing that company tagline footer to be printed on the backside of the page when the Word doc is printed.

I've tried setting text wrap of the footer image to extend to the edge of the page, but Word seems to override this and let one line of text be typed at the bottom of the page anyway. Same with placing an 8.5"x11" no-fill, no-stroke "invisible" rectangle in the header or footer of the page.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but you could set the page 2 header to take up the full page. That will stop people from typing into it. There are also some ways to lock the header.